# ios different ways of calling a method from different classes

Tags: iphone, ios, function, ios4

what are the different ways of calling a function from multiple classes?

i know protocals, notification but can any one describe all of them with example and which one is the best ?

thanks

Comment: Please define "best".

Comment: means what are the best practice used. and preferred .

Comment: that totally depends on what you want to do.  Have you read [Communicating with Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html) in the Apple Developer Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's so awful a question.  Lot of folks responded negatively to the "best" aspect of the question.  A simple rephrase might be "what circumstances are best suited for each kind of inter-object communication".

In summary the common ones are as follows:

- Direct invocation (google Objective-C language methods) - Most
  common, most direct, tightly collaborating objects.
- KVO (google "Objective-C KVO") - for a particular object to observe a particular
  value change in another.
- NSNotification (google "NSNotification") - for a any/many interested objects to observe any event another object wants to broadcast
- Delegate (google "Objective-C delegate") - when an object requires work to be done on it's behalf by some other object, it publishes a delegate protocol.  Other objects can implement this protocol ("conform to it") and then be assigned as the delegate.  (this one overused, in my opinion)

There's tons of web material on how to implement each (google them for details).

Comment: thanks bro for this, i will try to search out that and finding examples.

Comment: i could not find Direct invocation.

Comment: That's just calling a method. ClassA has an instance of ClassB which implements method 'foo'. It says: [myClassB foo];

Comment: oh you mean to say + functions

Comment: yes, but instance methods, too.  I just mean that the most basic way for classes to communicate is that one object has a handle to another and calls a method on it (class or instance method).  google "http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=objective+c+method+invocation&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8"